# How to resize VirtualBox disk?

Tags: virtualbox

To enlarge VirtualBox's vdi file, I tried like this.

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyhd "C:\Users\ironsand\VirtualBox VMs\Mint16Cinamon\Mint16Cinamon.vdi" --resize 8000
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resize hard disk operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

But as you see it failed.

Is there another way to enlarge virtualbox disk size?

I found this error happens when using fixed size virtual disk. But I'm using dynamic one.

This is details about the disk.

```
VBoxManage.exe showhdinfo "C:\Users\ironsand\VirtualBox VMs\Mint16Cinamon\Mint16Cinamon.vdi"
UUID:           a99bf1b5-5fbf-43a1-bb28-5233c70e8806
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       C:\Users\ironsand\VirtualBox VMs\Mint16Cinamon\Mint16Cinamon.vdi
Storage format: VDI
Format variant: dynamic default
Capacity:       8192 MBytes
Size on disk:   4046 MBytes
In use by VMs:  Mint16Cinamon (UUID: 66139117-48f3-45ed-8999-5402d2fbb124)
```

Comment: read the message, this is not supported

Comment: That's why I asked if there is OTHER way to do it

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood the `--resize` option.

With the option I should have set "result" size, not how much enlarge the size.
So I rewrote the command like this, then it works as I expected.

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyhd "C:\Users\ironsand\VirtualBox VMs\Mint16Cinamon\Mint16Cinamon.vdi" --resize 16000
```